# How can I mimic the iphone day view navigation bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode

I'm looking to copy the look and functionality of the 'day view' navigation controller from iphone calendar in my own app.  It's the control right under the navigation bar that lets you move to the previous and next days.

Is this built as a custom control?  If so how do I create it in code with a left arrow (button), 2 labels (one for day name and one for numerical date, and a right arrow (button)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at UILabel and UIButton. You can layout it using IB if you want.

Would be best to read a book for starting development for the iPhone first, I think.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but how do I group a button, label and another button together and assign them to the 'tableHeaderView'?